# Is there something for Internationalization in Php (PhpStorm) as we have in Java (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: php, intellij-idea, internationalization, phpstorm

When developing a Java application I can use a ResourceManger for internationalization (i18n). Many IDEs (like for example Intellij IDEA) support these files - I can click on the id in the call to the ResourceManager and get directly to the resource file. I can see in the resource file wich ids are actually used in the application and I have a graphical editor:

[image]

Is there something similar for PHP? In the application I am developing, we have a self-developed tool for i18n - clearly there is no IDE-support for that. I'd love to have similar IDE support in for example PhpStorm, since the power of the IDE support is blasting. What are possible solutions to this problem? Is it possible to do that in PhpStorm?

Comment: Nope -- nothing at all (except support for `*.po` files). PHP itself does not have any standard/widely used approach (that is used by vast majority of frameworks); plus AFAIK PhpStorm does not officially support any specific framework (WordPress/Drupal) at such hight level where it would provide any specific tools in this regard.

Comment: There's a `gettext()` / `.po` plugin for some of JetBrains IDE products: 

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7123?pr=

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with PhpStorm though

Comment: According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6946 there should be some support for gettext since PhpStorm version 5 ... it may only be active when using CakePHP though? 
(I'm not a PhpStorm user so I can only quote what Google found ...)

Comment: I developed a webapp to do that in my company. In such way, translations are not developer's business anymore :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes PHP has [Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) support. For PHPStorm its maybe difficult. but you can still use decent 3rd party apps for it such as [POEdit](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit)

Comment: Thanks risyasin. Not really the answer I hoped for, but since that seems to be the truth for this case, and since I didn't know POEdit yet - which is nice - there you go with your +50 ^_^

Comment: Jetbrains is just doing well. just a few more to get there the perfect IDE. one of the missing is gettext support. but i am hopeful about that, soon it will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Today phpStorm supported gettext and mo po files format. But not have native autocompile.

We can **add File Watcher for po-files autocompile**.
I allready have installed Poedit in my Windows 7. In directory GettextTools i found file "msgfmt.exe".

1. In phpStorm go to Settings - Tools - File Watchers.
2. Add new Watcher.
   [image: file Watcher]
3. This all! Now if you edit po-files then mo-files autocompile.

**Strings for Copy\Paste**:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\msgfmt

-o$FileDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.mo $FileDir$\$FileName$

$FileDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.mo

Comment: For linux:
msgfmt
-o $FileDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.mo $FileDir$/$FileName$
$FileDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.mo